# Developing a news feed system

Tags: rss, feed

I am developing a system that has a database for news headlines from various sources. I have not worked with RSS before so I am confused about a lot of things. Can anyone please point a good tutorial for how to develop such a thing? Thanks

In my mind, I have questions like:

1) How will I get the latest news feed? do I have to check the rss feed link every few minutes and see If it's different than the previous one?

2) Is it a good practice to parse the feed xml myself or use a feed reader kind of thing?

3) Will I have any control over the feed sent to me. e.g I only need news feed for Google or Intel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RSS is a very standard format you can start learning at [w3c school](http://www.w3schools.com/rss/).

About your questions.

1. If you can talk with the RSS provider, maybe they can notify each time
   something new comes. They can use, for example,
   [XML-RPC notification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC).

   You can also ask the RSS provider how often should you check the feed
   (in case they cannot provide any kind of notification).
2. I think it's better to develop your own bot. There is lot of
   frameworks that can deal with rss format. In case you are working with C# you can try with [SyndicationFeed Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx)
3. I'm not sure if I'm undestanding your problem, but if the provider
   puts a RSS link at your disposal, you must actively navigate that
   feed. When you have that feed, you can work with the metadata in
   order to see what's interesting for you. For example checking "category" or "channel" node.

Comment: Thanks. regarding question 1, if i put a little script in a cron job and it checks (after every hour) if the rss xml is updated, I don't need to talk to the RSS provider then?

Comment: Exact. If you can contact the provider and the provider can implement a notification system, do it. If not, just see how many articles comes by day and guess how often do you need to run the cron.